# Example from Doctrine 2 documentation

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Im new with Doctrine and start with their [tutorial](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/getting-started.html). 
Here is me bootstrap.php:

```
<?php
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

require_once "vendor/autoload.php";

$isDevMode = true;
$config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration(array(__DIR__."/src"), $isDevMode);


// database configuration parameters
$conn = array(
'driver' => 'pdo_sqlite',
'path' => __DIR__ . '/db.sqlite',
);

// obtaining the entity manager
$entityManager = EntityManager::create($conn, $config);
```

And my Products.php:.

```
<?php
// src/Product.php
/**
 * @Entity @Table(name="products")
 **/
class Product
{
/** @Id @Column(type="integer") @GeneratedValue **/
protected $id;
/** @Column(type="string") **/
protected $name;

public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

public function getName()
{
    return $this->name;
}

public function setName($name)
{
    $this->name = $name;
}
}
```

Now i do:

```
$ php vendor/bin/doctrine orm:schema-tool:update --force --dump-sql
```

But my db still empty i not get products table. Whats wrong?
Or i gonna create this table self?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to write something to DB to generate the *.sqlite file. Create any script to make that (like in the example) and look if your file has any content now

Comment: After make this command `$ php create_product.php ORM` I get error that doctrine cant find table products.

Answer (score 0):

I do all wrong. I gonna create class:

```
<?php
//doctrine-cli.php
use Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\HelperSet,
Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Helper\EntityManagerHelper,
Doctrine\DBAL\Tools\Console\Helper\ConnectionHelper,
Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\ConsoleRunner;
require_once __DIR__ . '/bootstrap.php';

$helperSet = new HelperSet(array(
'em' => new EntityManagerHelper($entityManager),
'conn' => new ConnectionHelper($entityManager->getConnection())
));
ConsoleRunner::run($helperSet);
```

And call doctrine commands like:

```
$ php doctrine-cli.php orm:schema-tool:update --force --dump-sql
```